# Discrepancies between ultrasound and calculated due date

Tags: pregnancy

How could a 4-week discrepancy in due date be explained between calculated due date and the due date a doctor calculates after the first ultrasound?

For example, if we received the 12. of November as due date from our doc after the first ultrasound, this would put us in 7th week.

However, if we use the day of the first last period (e.g. 14. of January) the due date would be: 20. of October.

So how could such a discrepancy be explained?

Comment: We had a similar experience, my wife had been pregnant four weeks longer than expected. The dating on the first scan is based solely on size, and up to a certain point, there’s basically no variation in size, so that’s really accurate.

Comment: 4 weeks longer makes sense, after all its possible to get a period while pregnant, but 4 weeks shorter? How could that be explained other than, the embryo stopped growing 4 weeks ago.

Comment: Well, they’d know if they had stopped growing, there’d be no heart beat.

Comment: @AJF: that's not very reassuring in this particular case if you read the entire question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Unfortunately medical questions are best asked to your doctor and not here; while I think the broad question is ok, it’s clear this is rooted in a specific medical question and that needs professional advice. Good luck!

Comment: @Joe I edited my question.

Comment: This is not a parenting question, it's a medical question. **Talk to your doctor or midwife about this.** If there is any concern, sequential scans will help.

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions on this site.

Comment: I feel like the general question - why can they be different - is okay, as it's a legitimate how-does-things-work question.  I'm still on the fence on this one, though, as it clearly comes from a "I have a problem right now" point of view.  Asked Rory to weigh in.  @user1721135 Regardless, please talk to your doctor, and please trust what they say - we can help explain the context around it, but we can't tell you anything about your own situation.

Answer (score 4):

Ultrasound is an estimate: measure the size and development of the fetus, and compare it to standard tables of development to figure out how far the pregnancy has progressed.  In the first trimester, [length measurement alone is used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown-rump_length).

A difference of 23 days at either 7 or 10 weeks of development is far outside the normal range of variation.  There are many things that could cause this, ranging from a bad measurement by the ultrasound technician, to a missed period causing conception to be later than believed, to development abnormalities.  **You'll need to consult with your doctor to find out which it is.**

Comment: could it also be that the ovulation happened so much later than calculated?

Comment: @user1721135, that's also a possibility.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. I bolded the most important takeaway, though. I hope that's ok. Feel free to roll back if it's not ok.